# Javascript and promises to do two async tasks

Tags: javascript, parsing, asynchronous, promise

I'm new to using promises in javascript but what I want to do is query two different tables and then do a third query using the results from the first two queries.

My issue is I can't seem to make my third query wait for both queries to finish.  It's usually a race condition to which query results it uses when in reality I want it to use both.

What would you suggest?

Here is what I'm attempting:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getLogs", (req, res) => {
  let q = new Parse.Query("logTable");
  let riderQuery = new Parse.Query("riders");
  let driverQuery = new Parse.Query("drivers");
  var ridePosts = [];
  driverQuery.equalTo("driver", req.user);
  riderQuery.equalTo("rider", req.user);
  riderQuery.include("ridePost");
  var promise = driverQuery.find().then(results => {
    ridePosts = results;
  });
  ridePosts.push(promise);
  riderQuery.find().then(results => {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var promise = results[i].get("ridePost");
      ridePosts.push(promise);
    }
  });

  Promise.all(ridePosts).then(values => {
    let allMatchingRides = ridePosts.concat(values);
    q.containedIn("participants", [req.user]);
    q.containedIn("rideRequest", allMatchingRides);
    q.find().then(logs => {
      res.success(logs);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Does `.get('ridePost');` really return a promise? If yes, then you want to more than just two things, and the code needs to be adjusted for that.

Comment: Yes ride post holds a pointer to another object.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting for more than two things? I push the get promise in a for loop so it's more than two promises.

Comment: *"My issue is I can't seem to make my third query wait for both queries to finish."* because you change the list of promises to wait for, all over the place. Why do you do `ridePosts = results`? What does `results` here contain? An array of values or an array of promises you want to wait for? And what is this `Promise.all(ridePosts).then(values => { let allMatchingRides = ridePosts.concat(values);`? Why do you concat an array of promises with the array of the resolved values of these promises? Plus one or two other places you'd have to adjust

Comment: @mocode10 of course there's a pointer, but is resolving the pointer actually an asynchronous action?

Comment: @mocode10 I just meant that "*I want to query two different tables and then do a third query using the results from the first two queries*" does not involve a loop with multiple promises.

Comment: I'm beyond confused now... I get I'm compounding promises and values now but how would I access the values in the promise as an array that I can compound onto my existing values array?

Comment: Try not to use `push` anywhere. Make an array of promises, or a promise for an array, and don't change the array afterwards. If you want to do anything with it, await the promise(s) and then build a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var driverPromise = driverQuery.find()
riderQuery.find().then(results => {
  var ridePromises = results.map(result => result.get('ridePost'))
  var promiseArray = ridePromises.concat([driverPromise])
  return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(values => {
    q.containedIn('participants', [req.user]);
    q.containedIn('rideRequest', values);
  })
})
.then(() => {q.find()})
.then(logs => res.success(logs))
```

I'm pretty sure you're looking for something like this. Let me explain, step by step.

- `driverPromise` is your first promise. I let it run and don't try and make it synchronous. I don't use `.then`
- I run `riderQuery.find()`. My return value is an array of more promises. I can `.map` over all of the promises and begin to run each of those promises with your `.get`. I set the array to be equal to `ridePromises`. I don't control the async nature of these running promises, because then
- I `.concat` `driverPromise` and `ridePromises` to form one array and use `Promise.all` make the code wait for everything all at once.

This line of code:

```
let allMatchingRides = ridePosts.concat(values);
```

is what is messing you up. Your `ridePosts` (very confusing variable names, by the way) is your array of promises, and then you're taking that array of promises and combining the array with `values`, the return value of your promises (???).

Comment: Implementing and testing now... but this post definitely changed how I view promises and async tasks.. Thank you, you're the real MVP

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this does throw an "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined*".

Comment: @mocode10 Please don't accept answers that cannot work.

Comment: @mocode10 edited. I didn't control the `Promise.all` so it ran before `ridePromises` was assigned those values.

Comment: This answer is very close. I am working on a solution but I'm pretty sure you can do driverPromise.then and then inside that Promise.all(riderPromises) and that should be the same since concat doesn't work on Promise array